# Redirect command error to variable in if statement

Tags: bash, tar, stderr

I'm creating a script and I would need to redirect the error of a command inside an if statement.

```
ERROR=""

if tar -xf $1 -C $2/$DIR_NAME 2> $ERROR;
then
    echo "Done"
else
    rm -rf $2/$DIR_NAME
    echo "Errors during execution:"
    echo $ERROR
fi
```

So, basically, I would like to print the errors that the `tar` command might trigger only after the `echo "Errors during execution:"`. When I execute the script I get a `line 20: $ERROR: ambiguous redirect` error.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect text into a variable, you need to capture it. But you want to keep the stderr text but not stdout:

```
if error=$( tar -xf "$1" -C "$2/$dir_name" 2>&1 1>/dev/null ); then ...
```

`if` will act on the exit status of tar.

Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES.

Comment: It works thank you! One question: why shouldn't I use caps name for vars? I use caps lock just because I can clearly see that they are not commands or reserved words but I'm very new at this, any input is well appreciated!

Comment: One day you'll write `PATH=foo` and then wonder why your script is broken. Leave all caps vars for the shell. Do you use all caps cars for other programming languages?